# I've been scammed and all my lumens are gone please help

Tags: xlm

've been hacked throw a staking email that looks genuine and takes me to a pretty genuine looking website when I've connected my wallet to stake the lumens they disappear. Please help all my savings are gone now...
tell me please there is a way of getting those lumens back

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to reverse a transaction on Stellar. You should report this scam to the police. No one on this forum can help you.

Comment: I did but they are not able to do anything...